# Using Next.js useRouter to pull title props not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Trying to display the title props from the Blog component from the index.js file.

Seems to just be blank when clicking on either one of the links.

**index.js**

```
import Layout from "../components/MyLayout";
import Link from "next/link";

const PostLink = props => (
  <li>
    <Link href="/p/[id]" as={`/p/${props.id}`}>
      <a>{props.id}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
);

const Blog = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      <ul>
        <PostLink id="hello-nextjs" title="Hello Next.js" />
        <PostLink id="learn-nextjs" title="Learn Next.js" />
        <PostLink id="deploy-nextjs" title="Deploy Next.js" />
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

This is the Post Component from the **[id].js** file. The {id} is displaying properly:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Layout from "../../components/MyLayout";

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { id, title } = router.query;

  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{id}</h1>
      <p>Title: {title}</p>
      <p>This is the blog post content from [id].js</p>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Post;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [NextJs Router doc](https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-routes-using-props-from-url), you haven't added `title` to query, so u need to append `?title=${props.title}` to href of Link

```
import Layout from "../components/MyLayout";
import Link from "next/link";

const PostLink = props => (
  <li>
    <Link href={`/p/[id]?title=${props.title}`} as={`/p/${props.id}`}>
      <a>{props.id}</a>
    </Link>
  </li>
);

const Blog = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>My Blog</h1>
      <ul>
        <PostLink id="hello-nextjs" title="Hello Next.js" />
        <PostLink id="learn-nextjs" title="Learn Next.js" />
        <PostLink id="deploy-nextjs" title="Deploy Next.js" />
      </ul>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

Comment: thanks but still coming out blank when trying to access from props

Comment: @StackUnderFlow, sorry, I missed your point, now I update the answer, u need to update Link `href={\`/p/[id]?title=${props.title}\`}`